# how to show dialog while calcs are being done?

Tags: knockout.js

I've created a spreadsheet with quite a few dependencies that take a few seconds to calculate. How can I show a dialog when:

a) the calcs are going
b) hide the dialog when the calcs are done

Not interested in trying to improve performance, just want to show a dialog to user to say system is working and then hide the dialog when done.

This is for knockout.js 3.4

Thank you!

Mark

Comment: Show dialog. Inside a `setTimeout`, do your calculations and hide the dialog.

Comment: Its not my calcs I'm waiting on, its the observables being updated (inside of knockout.js). Is there a awy to be informed when Knockout is done updating the observables?

Comment: Are they all computeds?

Comment: If you're using a large table, you might be suffering from Knockout's table problem.You may want to look at https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table

Comment: thanks for that link to the knockout-table

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of when things are calculating. Have an observable that tracks the number of calculations being performed. Each calculation (I'm assuming they are computed observables) should wrap its work like so:

```
vm.calculationCount(vm.calculationCount() + 1);
//...calculations here
setTimeout(function () { vm.calculationCount(vm.calculationCount() - 1)}, 10);
```

The timeout acts as a debounce, to keep from showing calculations done if they're running sequentially.

You'd show your dialog when `calculationCount() > 0`, hide it when `calculationCount() === 0`. Depending on how your dialog works, you might want a computed (or just a function) that returns true or false based on those comparisons.

Comment: I appreciate the help trying to figure this out, however this isn't what I'm looking for. I just want to know when Knockout is done updating itself via observables. I don't really want to keep track of everything by hand, there should be some method/hook that I could use, but maybe not.

Comment: What I did find was that .extend({ rateLimit: 25 }); allowed the table to update reasonable quickly and you can see the updates that are taking place, which is an alternative, I just needed the user to see something, although a message would be best...

Comment: I am not aware of any "Knockout is busy propagating subscriptions" hook, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
showDialog();
doCalculations();
hideDialog();
```

This might sound stupid but, if you didn't set any timeouts (such as .rate()) on your observables/computeds, then by the time you reached the `hideDialog();` the view should be updated.

**EDIT:**
But if you insist on keeping your throttles and rate-limits, then you could subscribe the `hideDialog` function call to a computed which contains all of your computeds that are updating, but first add a throttle to that "master computed". So now after all the changes to the observed computations stop and the throttle/timeout ends, your dialog should be hidden.